# Capturing variable in ajaxoptions yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to capture javascript/PHP variable in the ajaxoptions' options. e.g;

```
CHtml::ajaxLink("My link", Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/definition'), array(
                'data' => array("id" => $model->id),
                'type' => 'POST',
                'error' => 'js:function(data){}',
                'beforeSend' => 'js:function(request){}',
                'success' => 'js:function(data){
                         alert(jQuery(this).attr("id"));
                         alert({$model->id});
                 }',
                'complete' => 'js:function(data){}',
                    //'update'=>'#where_to_put_the_response',
                    ), array(
                "confirm" => "Are you sure you want to delete?",
                        "id" => "linkID",
                        "href" => "javascript:;",
                        "title" => "mTitle"
                    )
            );
```

In the success option I have two alerts to show you guyz how do i want it. Which doesn't display correct data. Is there any way to get the php variables and the jQuery(this) object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have extracted the data i wanted from "jQuery(this)". Actually "jQuery(this)" returned me the data in a different format. Below is the code.

```
   CHtml::ajaxLink("My link", Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/definition'), array(
                    'data' => array("id" => $model->id),
                    'type' => 'POST',
                    'error' => 'js:function(data){}',
                    'beforeSend' => 'js:function(request){
                          mdata=(jQuery(this)[0]["data"]).replace( /^\D+/g, "");
                     }',
                    'success' => 'js:function(data){
                             alert(mdata);
                     }',
                    'complete' => 'js:function(data){alert(mdata);}',
                        //'update'=>'#where_to_put_the_response',
                        ), array(
                    "confirm" => "Are you sure you want to delete?",
                            "id" => "linkID",
                            "href" => "javascript:;",
                            "title" => "mTitle"
                        )
                );
```

if alert the "jQuery(this)" like `alert(JSON.stringify(jQuery(this)));` - you will get the idea of the data returned.